# ownerDocument error when using jQuery's scrollTop & animate functions

Tags: jquery, window, jquery-animate, undefined, scrolltop

I've stumbled across a very strange bug. I'm using jQuery scrollTop to let the window scroll to the position of the .extrasWarning class whenever that class is out the window's sight. This is the following code:

```
$('[data-required] .number select').change(function () {
var number = $(this).closest('.choice_data').data('required'),
windowPos = $(window).height(),
selectedAmount = 0;
alert(windowPos);
$(this).closest('.choice_data').find('.number option:selected').each(function (i) {
  selectedAmount = selectedAmount + parseInt($(this).val());
});
if (selectedAmount > number) {
  $(this).closest('.choice_data').next('.extrasWarning').show();
  var errorPos = $(this).closest('.choice_data').next('.extrasWarning').offset().top;
  alert(errorPos);
  if (errorPos > windowPos) {
    $(window).animate({
      scrollTop: errorPos
    }, 1000);
  }
} else {
  $('.extrasWarning').hide();
}
});
```

When I use the  element to choose another option, all the events fire properly, except the $(window).animate function. FireFox displays the following error: a.ownerDocument is undefined.

The problem lies with using the animate function in combination with the scrollTop function. If I implement the following change:

```
if (errorPos > windowPos) {
  $(window).scrollTop(errorPos);
}
```

it suddenly works fine! However, I really want to use the animate function. Any idea how I can make this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try animating body and html elements:

```
  if (errorPos > windowPos) {
    $("body, html").animate({
      scrollTop: errorPos
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. When using $(document), the FireFox JS console displays the following error: a.ownerDocument is null. Instead   of "undefined" this time.

Comment: @MartijnvanTurnhout try html and body elements.

Comment: The 'html & body' combination works fine! Your vote is coming up!

Answer (score 0):

<s>`$(elem).animate` animates CSS properties, and the scroll position isn't one.</s> Not true; if the given property is not a CSS property, jQuery treats it as an element property instead.

Anyway, there's a not-very-well-known use for `animate` *without* dom elements, instead animating whatever values you please:

```
var jWin = $(window);
var currentPos = jWin.scrollPos();
$({pos: currentPos}).animate(
    {pos: errorPos},
    {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function () { jWin.scrollTop(this.pos) },
        complete: function () { jWin.scrollTop(errorPos); }
    }
);
```

This animates `pos` from the current scroll position to the intended destination `errorPos`. In the `step` function, you set the actual scroll position accordingly.

The `complete` step is necessary because `step` usually isn't called with the final value.

Comment: scrollTop works fine with the animate function! I had to use 'html, body' instead of the 'window' selector though. That was it. But thanks for your input anyhow! :)

Comment: Yeah, the "it only animates CSS was wrong", Once again jQuery outsmarted me ;p You just needed the animated object to be and actual dom element (which neither `window` nor `document` are).